# Easy way of seeing if swapping summation is ok? (Generating functional derivation of Bell numbers)

Tags: summation, generating-functions

On page 21 of his book `generatingfunctionology` (available for [free on the author's homepage](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html)), the author rearranges the summations in the following way:

\begin{align}
b(n)
&= \sum^M_{k=1} \sum^k_{r=1} (-1)^{k-r} \frac{r^{n-1}}{(r-1)!(k-r)!}
\\
&= \sum^M_{r=1} \frac{r^{n-1}}{(r-1)!} \sum^M_{k=r} \frac{(-1)^{k-r}}{(k-r)!}
\end{align}

It is not immediately obvious to me that this is in fact correct. I have convinced myself for some values of $M$ that I indeed get the same set of ordered pairs $(k,r)$. But is there a way that I can immediately show that the second line is equivalent to the first?

Comment: geometrically?  You're adding up the values at the lattice points of the triangle with vertices at $(1,1)$, $(1,M)$, and $(M,M)$.  The first line you're adding up the vertical  lines bottom to top first, horizontal left to right in the second.

Comment: @mSSM Just so you know, the title of the book is *generatingfunctionology*

Comment: @Callus: That's a very cute way of putting it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:* Maybe the following representation of indices is helpful

> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=1}^{M}\sum_{r=1}^{k}b_{r,k}=\sum_{1\leq r\leq k\leq M}b_{r,k}=\sum_{r=1}^{M}\sum_{k=r}^Mb_{r,k}
> \end{align*}